# How to get 5 biggest values from multiple sheets in Google Sheets?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, formula

I need to take five better values from the sheets "Lap1" and "Lap2" and put them in the Sheet "Biggest" for every team and sort them from the biggest to the smallest.

I tried the query formula but couldn't write it correctly.

Expected values:

Team 1: 12 4 3 2 2

Team 2: 12 8 7 5 4

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1HMMTVWTSAI4jIIY6MGBx4tARswFnLGwOtP6B8rLA_-8/edit#gid=936304041

Comment: Consider providing input and expected output as **plain text table** in the question. [Click here](//webapps.stackexchange.com/a/161855) to create a table easily, which are **easy to copy/paste**.  Avoid sharing [links like spreadsheets](//meta.stackoverflow.com/a/260455) or [images](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551) as the only source of data, as they're hard to copy from. Also, note that [your email address can also be accessed by the public](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/394304), if you share Google files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*You may try this in your `Biggest` tab:*

```js
=map(D4:D,lambda(Σ,if(Σ="",,let(Λ,{{'Lap1'!G:R,'Lap1'!D:D};{'Lap2'!F:Q,'Lap2'!D:D}},
     torow(sortn(tocol(ifna(filter(choosecols(Λ,sequence(12)),choosecols(Λ,13)=Σ)),1),5,,1,))))))
```

[image]

Comment: I need to make a small change to the table.  If a team doesn't have points, there has to be a "0" in every empty cell. Like in the screenshot [link](https://ibb.co/pr5p3Mm). Your formula is complicated, and I can't manage to fix it myself.

Comment: Replace this part of the formula `'Lap1'!G:R` with `index(if(len('Lap1'!G:R),'Lap1'!G:R,0))` and test